# Color management affetcs video sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, color-management

I try to match my scene to a reference video (which I have loaded into the Video sequence editor) by changing settings in the Color management tab such as contrast, exposure or gamma. However, this also affects the clip in the Sequencer. How can I prevent this or use another color management for the video sequencer?

Answer (score -1):

Press N in the Sequencer and in the Side Panel Just head over to Modifiers and add any modifier you want to add to manage your look of the clip

Hope this may Solve your Problem

[image]